# Show that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[-n,n]=\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[-n,n]=\mathbb{R}$

This is intuitive to me, as the limits for the interval eventually is $\infty$ and $-\infty$, but how do I prove it?

Perhaps something like this?

Since $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \rightarrow \infty$, so $[-n,n] \rightarrow [-\infty, \infty] = \mathbb{R}$

But it seems that the information regarding the union is "missing" from my attempt... thanks, in advance. I'm trying to learn some more "proof based" math, i.e. more abstract than calculus and that level.

Comment: You need to use the definition of union. The statement is equivalent to "for all $x\in \mathbb R,$ there is an $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $x\in [-n,n]$". The truth of this statement should be pretty clear (but if you feel obligated to be very rigorous and prove it, the keyword is "Archimedean property". )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:[-n,n]\in\mathbb{R}\Longrightarrow\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[-n,n]\subseteq\mathbb{R}.$$

To find the other inclusion you take $r\in\mathbb{R}$ randomly. Then there exist an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|r|<N$. This implies that $r\in[-N,N]\subseteq\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[-n,n]$. Because $r$ was chosen randomly we get $\mathbb{R}\subseteq\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[-n,n]$.

$$\Longrightarrow\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[-n,n]=\mathbb{R}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it by "double inclusion": proving $A=B$ is equivalent to saying (1) $A \subset B$ and (2) $B \subset A$.

In your case, each interval of the form $[-n,n]$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$, and the union is again a subset of $\mathbb R$. So clearly $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} [-n,n] \subset \mathbb R$. On the other hand, any real number $r$ is less than some (large enough) natural number $m$, so that $r \in [-m,m]$, and hence $r \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} [-n,n]$. The latter shows $\mathbb R \subset \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} [-n,n]$.